# What did apt-get purge do?

Tags: python, linux

Newbie to linux, I thought that `apt-get purge` is usually used to remove a pkg totally, but today it neally crash my whold system. I want to remove a previously installed `python 3.4` distribution, but I'm not sure which pkg it belongs, so I used `find /usr -type f -name "python3.4"` to find it, the command returns several lines, the first one is `/usr/bin/python3.4`, so then I typed `dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3.4` to determine which pkg python3.4 belongs, it returns `python-minimal`, so I typed `sudo apt-get purge python-minimal`, but then a lot of pkgs was removed, also some installed, I'm totally confused, and I saw even the app store disappeared, a lot of the system was removed... Can someone help me?

Comment: See [I run `sudo apt-get remove python2.7`, how can I restore...?](https://askubuntu.com/q/187227/8005) and [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/8005)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `apt purge <package>` or `apt remove <package>` you are not only instructing `apt` to remove the named package, but any other package that depends on it. Of course `apt` doesn't perform that unexpected operation without first asking for your consent, so I imagine it showed the list of packages that it was going to remove, and when you pressed `Y` it removed all of them.

So, to undo the mess, if you still have the window where you run the `purge` then check which packages it told you it was going to remove, and manually `apt install` them. If you don't have the list around, then you need to manually install every package that is not working properly.

If it is the window manager that got damaged, try `apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` or the appropriate package for your distribution/window manager.

Rule of thumb when deleting/updating packages: *always read the list of packages affected*, sometimes there is unexpected stuff.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm confused that would so many pkgs, even the software center depends on python?

Comment: Likely yes, anything that is written in python will depend on it.

Comment: luckily it does not remove the gnome desktop, and terminal still works, so I typed `sudo apt-get install unbuntu-desktop ` then everything seems recovered, but I'm not sure if all of the removed things recovered

Comment: so, it means that after setting my ubuntu, there is already a `python3.4`  pkg installed in it? but what the relation between that  `python3.4`  and my later installed `python3.6` ?

Comment: It's possible that you have several versions of python if you have software that depends on different versions, but normally that software specifies the dependency as `python3.x` or `python2.x` so you'll end up with only two versions. In the case you have multiple `python3.x` they'll end up in their own folder, and you can select which one to use by default using the `update-alternatives` command.

Comment: Look at [this page](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux) for an explanation of how to use `update-alternatives` for python. Summarizing you'll need to issue a pair of `update-alternatives --install` before the command is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I will share a most convenient way of finding what command/file belongs to what package in the system

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
# which python
sudo apt-file find bin/python
```

I am using Debian, but above method could help with Ubuntu, I think

Note the searching path `bin/python` didn't have to be a full path could be a substring of the real path, as every Debian package will put executable in a `bin/` folder, it's very convenient to find with `bin/CommandName`

Comment: I see, thank you, I know `apt-file search `command, I'm wondering if  `apt-file find bin/python` and `dpkg -S bin/python` behaves the same?

Comment: No, `apt-file find` will gives you all the packages in the repo, you should first run `apt-file update` first to get the cache from the server first, and `dpkg -S`  will only give you installed results, I use this command to find package needed to be installed when specific file was not find :D